# How do I boot a Linux LiveCD on a Lenovo Yoga?

Tags: boot, lenovo, live-cd

I just bought the book Hacking: The Art of Exploitation and it comes with a Linux LiveCD that is pre-installed with Ubuntu and a bunch of Source Code. on my desktop computer(running Windows 7) I insert the disc and reboot and it loads. When I insert the disc into my external DVD drive connected to my Lenovo Yoga(Running Windows 8.1) and reboot, it boots directly to Windows. How do I get it to boot to the LiveCD?

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069 and read the section on YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press ESC as soon as your laptop boots..better press ESC continuously as soon as you power on the laptop.This will give various BIOS options.Press Function Keys as required.I can't tell which one as they are different from brand to brand.Somewhere you will find an option for boot sequence.Make sure your Linux Disc(Exteenal DVD drive) is above everything.Also turn boot mode from UEFI to Legacy if required.

Comment: What will changing from UEFI to Legacy do? Sorry, I'm rather new to this sort of thing.

Comment: It helps in booting non-windows OS like Linux and even older Windows version like XP

Comment: When go into to startup options in the BIOS, I see a line that says something like: UEFI/Legacy Boot - CSM Support [UEFI Only] [No] *Unselectable for Secure Boot. Does this mean I can't change to Legacy?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Just had to disable secure boot and enable legacy boot and it booted just fine. Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an easier solution, you should boot this an USB key.
Copy the ISO from your favorite distribution's website on your USB key with Lili USB Creator, then boot on your USB key.
You should also check your boot preferences on your BIOS/UEFI, check also on Google what is the alternate boot key for Llenovo.

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Right next to the power switch there is a little button that you'll need to press & hold with a small screw driver/pin.

Arrow down to Boot Menu and click Enter.

Arrow down to the HDD (DVD drive) and click enter.

If that doesn't work, disable secure boot and enable legacy boot.